# how to make text stay after the search has been made

Tags: django

I have a serch field on my page

```
<form method="GET" class="container mb-5">
<input type="search" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Write a name" aria-label="Search"
        aria-describedby="search-addon" name="search"/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-5" >Search</button>
</form>
```

And here is my views

```
def my_view(request):
    value_one = request.GET.get("search", None)
    objects = MyModel.objects.all()
    if value_one:
        objects = objects.filter(field_one=value_one)
```

After I input something in a search field and push the button 'search', text which was in search field dissapears, I want it to stay until the next input. Is it possible to do with Django or not? Don't even know how to google it, everything I found was on different topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your template add value to your input:

```
<form method="GET" class="container mb-5">
<input type="search" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Write a name" aria-label="Search" value="{{value_one"}}
        aria-describedby="search-addon" name="search"/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-5" >Search</button>
</form>
```

and on your view add that value to your context :

```
    def my_view(request):
        value_one = request.GET.get("search", None)
        objects = MyModel.objects.all()
        if value_one:
            objects = objects.filter(field_one=value_one)
        return render(request,'template.html',{'value_one':value_one,'objects':objects})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [django's `Form` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) ? You should be using the `Form` class to create forms in Django and that would allow you to preserve data between "submit" calls as well as handle errors. Some example code snippets for you:

> forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(label="Search Query", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control rounded", "placeholder": "Write a name", "aria-label": "Search", "aria-describedby": "search-addon"}))
```

> views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SearchForm


def my_view(request):
    form = SearchForm({"search": request.GET.get("search", None)})
    if form.is_valid():
        search_query = form.cleaned_data.get("search")
        if search_query:
            objects = MyModel.objects.filter(field_one=search_query).all()
    
    # ...snip...
    return render(request, 'searchform.html', {"form": form})
```

> searchform.html

```html
<form action="{% url 'my_view' %}" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-5">
</form>
```